# How do I pass data from one component to another?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am trying to pass `this.state.airQualityData` from AirPollutionApi class to the Home class via props (props.data). How would I do that?

This is my code:

**AirPollutionApi Class:**

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import Home from '../Home';


var API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY

class AirPollutionApi extends Component {

    //API preparation, state management, and location management
    state = {
        airQualityData: {},
        latitude: undefined,
        longitude: undefined
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.retrieveLocation()
        await this.fetchAirQualityData()
    }

    fetchAirQualityData = () => {
        return fetch(
            `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution?lat=${this.state.latitude}&lon=${this.state.longitude}&appid=${API_KEY}`
        )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                airQualityData: data
            })
        })
    }

    retrieveLocation = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                this.state.latitude = position.coords.latitude
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                this.state.longitude = position.coords.longitude
                resolve();
            })
        })
    }


    // Getting all data from API 
    getAQIValue = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].main.aqi * 100
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }

    getCOValue = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].components.co
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }

    getNH3Value = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].components.nh3
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }

    getNOValue = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].components.no
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }

    getO3Value = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].components.o3
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }

    getPM2_5Value = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].components.pm2_5
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }

    getPM10Value = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].components.pm10
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }

    getSO2Value = () => {
        if(this.state.airQualityData.list){
            return this.state.airQualityData.list["0"].components.so2
        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    }


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.airQualityData)

        return (
            
            
            <div>

                {/* TRYING TO PASS THE 'this.state.airQualityData' HERE */}
                {/* AQI */}
                {this.props.data.includes("aqi") || this.props.data.includes("AQI")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.aqiStyle} className='aqi-value'>
                        {this.getAQIValue()}
                    </div>
                : null}
                
                {/* CO */}
                {this.props.data.includes("co") || this.props.data.includes("CO")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.coStyle} className='co-value'>
                        {this.getCOValue()}
                    </div>
                : null}

                {/* NH3 */}
                {this.props.data.includes("nh3") || this.props.data.includes("NH3")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.nh3Style} className='nh3-value'>
                        {this.getNH3Value()}
                    </div>
                : null}

                {/* NO */}
                {this.props.data.includes("no") || this.props.data.includes("NO")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.noStyle} className='no-value'>
                        {this.getNOValue()}
                    </div>
                : null}
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AirPollutionApi;
```

**Home Class (trying to pass data to the  component via 'props.data'):**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactSpeedometer from 'react-d3-speedometer';

import AirPollutionApi from './utils/airPollutionApi'

const Home = (props) => {


    return (
        
        <div>
            <h1 style={{fontFamily: "Montserrat", textAlign: "center", fontSize: "300%"}}>
                AQI:
            </h1>
            <ReactSpeedometer value={props.data} maxValue={500} minValue={0} />
            <AirPollutionApi data=""/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

I tried putting the Home component in the return of the AirPollutionApi like this:

```
return (
            
            
            <div>

                <Home data={this.state.airQualityData}/>

                {/* AQI */}
                {this.props.data.includes("aqi") || this.props.data.includes("AQI")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.aqiStyle} className='aqi-value'>
                        {this.getAQIValue()}
                    </div>
                : null}
                
                {/* CO */}
                {this.props.data.includes("co") || this.props.data.includes("CO")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.coStyle} className='co-value'>
                        {this.getCOValue()}
                    </div>
                : null}

                {/* NH3 */}
                {this.props.data.includes("nh3") || this.props.data.includes("NH3")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.nh3Style} className='nh3-value'>
                        {this.getNH3Value()}
                    </div>
                : null}

                {/* NO */}
                {this.props.data.includes("no") || this.props.data.includes("NO")  ? 
                
                    <div style={this.props.noStyle} className='no-value'>
                        {this.getNOValue()}
                    </div>
                : null}
                
            </div>
        )
```

But it just crashes the localhost.

**EDIT:**

I figured out that whenever I add the AirPollutionApi component to the Home, that is the reason why the localhost is crashing. However, if i don't add it, then props.data doesn't get any data from  component in the AirPollutionApi class.

Comment: Think about using a state management solution like redux. Typically when you want to pass data across components, it will make work much easier.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think I will most likely use that.

Answer (score 0):

In airPollutionApi Class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY

class AirPollutionApi extends Component {
    // ...your existing code

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Home data={this.state.airQualityData} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AirPollutionApi;
```

and In Home :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactSpeedometer from 'react-d3-speedometer';

const Home = (props) => {
    const airQualityData = props.data; // data received from props

    // ...rest of the code

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{ fontFamily: "Montserrat", textAlign: "center", fontSize: "300%" }}>
                AQI:
            </h1>
           
            <ReactSpeedometer value={getAQIValue(airQualityData)} maxValue={500} minValue={0} />
          
        </div>
    );
};

// Function to get AQI value from airQualityData
const getAQIValue = (data) => {
    if (data && data.list) {
        return data.list[0].main.aqi * 100;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: When I do this, it returns undefined when I am calling the function, which means that the props.data is not getting any data. I confirmed this by console logging

Comment: log the airQualityData in airPollutionApi Class and check it contains data or not

Comment: I checked the logs, and it does contain data. 

Basically, the main problem right now is that it returns undefined, but when I add "<AirPollutionApi />" in the code then it doesn't return undefined, but instead just crashes my localhost.

I've tried logging when this happens and all that it outputs is just an infinite amount of 'undefined' in the console.

Comment: I fixed the crashing issue by moving the <Home /> component from return to render in AirPollutionApi, but it doesn't give any data to the props.